# Not creating a copy with ffload

Tags: r, copy, bigdata, ffbase

I have a question about a function attribut from the ff package.
I have an ff object in a specific directory I want to load. This is what I am using:

```
setwd(~/Documents/Data)
ffload("Object", overwrite=TRUE)
```

With OVERWRITE=TRUE, a copy of the object will be saved in a tmp folder and the object will be load from this directory:

```
[1] "tmp/Rtmpsj1b2f/clone11876c2c0949.ff"
```

But if you don't want a copy of your object you need to put FALSE to overwrite. If it is the first time you load your ff object it will create a copy in a tmp folder even if overwrite=FALSE! Then I deleted the copy, and re-loaded the object for the second time, I had the following message and no copy:

```
Warning :
In FUN("Obs_zone_212_19700801_19750731"[[1L]], ...) :
did not overwrite object 'Obs_zone_212_19700801_19750731'
```

The problem is that I am working with a lot of big files and I don't want to create copies! What can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it is good to give an explanation about `ffload` for your case

You have 2 files in your ~/Documents/Data directory. One called `Object` and another one called `Object.ffData`. `Object.ffData` contains the ff files with the **raw** data. `Object` contains an R workspace with the **virtual** attributes of the ff files (like levels e.g., pointers to the ff files, ...) which is only a few Kb depending on your data structure.

ffload unzips the ff files which are contained in `Object.ffData` into the folder where you have created the ff files (see `getOption("fftempdir")` - for your case this was in the tmp/Rtmpsj1b2f folder. If you specify the `rootpath` argument to ffload, you can unzip the ff files to another directory. As in `ffload("Object", overwrite=TRUE, rootpath = "/home/myname/myfolder")`. The overwrite argument of ffload indicates that if that ff file which you are unzipping already existed in that directory, it will overwrite it. So far the ff part.

When loading with ffload your file, you are also loading the virtual part in your R session. This is for your case an object which you have named `Obs_zone_212_19700801_19750731` (see `ls()`). The warning you see is that when ffloading your new data, it did not overwrite this object. So you need to `rm(Obs_zone_212_19700801_19750731)` before ffloading to get rid of the warning.

Hope this helps. 
If your data are ffdf objects, you can also look at `save.ffdf` from package `ffbase`. This does not zip your data but keeps it straight on disk.

Comment: Thank you for this answer! So in fact my problem comes from ffsave. Before loading the ff objects, I created them with ffsave. When I use ffsave, it will create Object.RData and Object.ffdata in the directory I choose and another folder in tmp (the Rtmpsj1b2f folder). If I don't want to have this last folder I need to add the roothpath I want in ffsave?

Comment: You should set the fftempdir folder before creating the ff objects to a folder where you want your ff files to be located. options(fftempdir = "path/to/your/folder")

Comment: Ok! When I add that, I have en error: cannot open file '/tmp/RtmpBHIZfb/file1a8256d52308' : No such file. It seems that even if I asked for a specific folder it doesn't work

Comment: You need to set fftempdir **before** creating the ff objects